# Is it possible to limit lines to search through in Type | Find operation

Tags: batch-file, find

I need to iterate over multiple text files but exclude some based on name or content.
What I have right now, searches through the entire file. This takes pretty long and is unnecessary.
I want the (Type "%%f" | FIND "") to only search through the first few lines.

```
for %%f in (*.ifc) do (
    (Echo "%%f" | FIND /I "optimized" 1>NUL) || (
        (Type "%%f" | FIND /I "Solibri IFC Optimizer" 1>NUL) || (
            echo do some stuff with file
)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Neither `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` nor `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` support searching only in the first X lines in a file. Otherwise the help output on running `find /?` and `findstr /?` in a command prompt window or the Microsoft documentation of these two [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) would mention that somewhere.

Comment: It would be possible to read the lines in the files with `cmd.exe` itself using a `for /F` loop for each file with exiting the loop after search for a string in the first X lines of a file. But if the files have not hundreds of MB and the lines to search for a string is not with the first 20 lines, this approach would be even slower than searching the entire files with __FIND__ or __FINDSTR__. I think, best would be forgetting the idea to do that with a batch file as `cmd.exe` is designed for executing commands and executables and not for text file processing.

Comment: My recommendations: Use VBScript or JScript processed by Windows Script Host or PowerShell or Python or other more modern and more powerful script interpreters than the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file or code a real program in C/C++/C# for this special text searching purpose in many files.

Comment: PS: Filtering the files to search for a string by file name is easy with either a better wildcard pattern or using a `for /F` loop running a command line with __DIR__ to get a list of file names piped to __FINDSTR__ to filter out all file names matching a specific simple regular expression.

Comment: Inside your `for %%f` loop, you could play around with something like `findstr /N "^" "%%~f" | findstr /R /C:"^[1-9]:" /C:"^[1-9][0-9]:"`, which would return only the first 99 lines, for example, which you could iterate with a `for /F` loop…

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a JScript code section to limit the number of lines to just the first 10 of each file:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   echo File: %%f
   < "%%f" CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" | find /N /V ""
   echo ================
   echo/
)
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section: show just a given number of input lines

var fso    = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
    stdIn  = fso.GetStandardStream(0),
    stdOut = fso.GetStandardStream(1);

for ( var i=1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
   stdOut.WriteLine(stdIn.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to do, i.e. optimize each IFC file in the current directory, which does not contain the string `Solibri IFC Optimizer`, and which does not have the substring `_optimized`, in its filename, then the obvious thing to do would be to filter everything within your `for` loop. It is much more efficient to filter earlier in the chain, than to do it later. For example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SIO=%ProgramFiles%\Solibri\IFCOptimizer\Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe"
Echo Optimizing previously unoptimized IFC files in the current directory.
For /F "Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^FILE_NAME("
 *.ifc ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /VRC:"_optimized\.ifc:"
 /C:"(Solibri IFC Optimizer)"') Do "%SIO%" -in="%%G" …
```

Please remember to adjust the variable value for `SIO` as needed. You'll also need to adjust the command on the last line command, I've currently only included the `-in` parameter. I'll leave it to you to determine whether you need to include an `-out` file/directory parameter, and choose between a `-ifc` or `-ifczip` compression parameter. However, I will assume that you most likely will want to including the `-force` parameter, as it appears that you're overwriting the originals with the default `-suffix` of `_optimized`.

As a side note, you may find that because this involves invoking a seperate instance of `Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe` for each previously unoptimized file, that you may wish to consider creating a semi-colon seperated listing of filenames from the `for` loop. Then use that with the `-in` parameter, *(`-in=file1;file2;file3;…`)*. That would only invoke a simgle instance of `Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe`, which would probably be more efficient.